# ServiceWorker does not intercept script request from dynamically loaded page

Tags: service-worker

I have implemented service worker with .net core web application. app is single page and load other pages via jquery load function. 
The main page has cache which has all the resources needed for application to run completely offline. 
So far so good,  scope of worker is set to / level. All works until I notice that script that are on dynamically loaded page or partial view does not served by worker although they are in cache. Service worker do serve them on main page.

This gives me impression that whatever the scope of service worker is it will not serve cache on dynamically loaded partial pages but only on page where it’s activated on.

How can I make main page serve cache on those dynamically loaded partial views? How service worker decided where to serve resource from cache? If scope is set to root then why not serve script?

I have read so many documents about it but no where I read that whatever the scope of service worker is, it will only serve on page it’s activated on, no matter if you load page dynamically without real page navigation.

EDIT:

Found it. Probably it will save someone some time & headache. The partial page load is via jquery load function, which needs to parse html and script synchronously and the **fetch doesn't intercept if request is synchronous**. Now need to find a workaround.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, there should not be this sort of limitation. But it's very hard to help without seeing your Service Worker code. Could you add that?

Comment: @Pete, thanks for comment. I’ll post the code asap. I  am convinced it’s happening.